# Broken BURG install after backup/restore

Tags: 12.04, burg

Long story short:  BURG is stuck in text mode and I can't seem to get it back to the eye-candy.  I have purged and then re-installed to no avail.  I am running 12.04.

The long story:  I originally installed onto 12.04 using Super-boot-manager (BURG-manager) and then stopped using it in favour of GRUB because I had too many entries.  I then had to backup and restore Ubuntu (partition was deleted and re-created) due to unrelated issues.  I re-installed GRUB2 and booted into Ubuntu to re-install BURG, but after re-booting it appears to be stuck in text mode (looks exactly like GRUB 1).

Any ideas?  I know I'm not supposed to be using it on 12.04 (I think) but it worked before, so what's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be gone after a reinstall of entire multiboot - but I still don't know why.  I'm also rather afraid to touch it because the problem could come back!

Answer (score 1):

You need to uninstall BURG with:

```
sudo apt-get purge burg burg-common burg-pc burg-themes burg-themes-common
```

And manually delete "burg" folder in "/boot".

After this install BURG again.

Comment: I'd done that with no luck.